# Set of homomorphisms of abelian group is noncommutative ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

This is question I faced

Question : Prove that the set of group homomorphism for abelian group $A$ is a noncommutative ring with 1.

So, I showed every conditions for ring with 1. But, is it true that for every abelian group $A$, there exists two homomorphisms $f, g$ such that $fg !=gh$?

It is easy if $f, g$ are just functions, not homomorphisms. How can I show it?

Answer (score 1):

The result is not always true. $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z)$ has two elements, the trivial homomorphism and the identity that commute.

Comment: Ah, it looks like my instructor made some mistake while making questions. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The endomorphism ring of a cyclic group is always commutative.